# Very basic questions on chain rules and product rules

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

I have serious gaps in maths and would like to ask some basic questions.

1. I know there is the following chain rule for the first derivative: 
   $$ Dh(x) = Dg(f(x))Df(x)\quad\quad (1) $$
   where $h(x) = g(f(x))$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^p$.
   There also is the following rule for the second derivative:
   $$ \nabla^2h(x) = g'(f(x)) \nabla^2 f(x) + g''(f(x)) \nabla f(x)\nabla f(x)^\top, \quad\quad (2) $$
   but restricted to $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. My question: is there any chain rule for the second derivative in the general case: $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^p$?
2. I tried to prove $(2)$ using $\nabla^2h(x) = D\nabla h(x)$:
   From $(1)$ we have $\nabla h(x)= g'(f(x)) \nabla f(x)$. Now we need to calculate the derivative of a product, which implies my second question: is there a product rule for $D(fg)(x)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?
3. Is there a (dot) product rule for $D(f\cdot g)(x)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$?
4. Could you please suggest a textbook with complete theory (theorems and proofs) and many examples and/or problems with solutions (on calculating the derivative)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For questions 2) and 3):

your question is adressed via the same argument:
if $B$ is a continuous bilinear map, it is differentiable and
$$
DB(x,y) = B(Dx,y) + B(x,Dy).
$$

Here you have the map $(x,y)\to xy$ (or $x\cdot y$) and 
$$
D(f\cdot g) = (Df)\cdot g + f\cdot Dg.
$$

Comment: For the (normal) product I think it is clear: $D(fg) = g(Df)+ f(Dg)$, which gives an $m\times n$ matrix (recall that in this case: $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: For the case of dot product (now $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$), when you write $(Df)\cdot d$ and $f\cdot Dg$, it is not mathematically correct, isn't it? Because $Df$ and $Dg$ are $m\times n$ whereas $f$ and $g$ are $m\times 1$ (except if we have a definition for the dot product between a vector and a matrix, but do we?). So shouldn't the answer be: $D(f\cdot g) = g^\top (Df) +f^\top(Dg)$?

Thanks again.

Comment: if $f:E\to F$ the $Df:E\to F$ also with my notations.

Comment: Thanks, @mookid. Do you have any ideas for 1) and 4)? :D

Comment: for 1. I have no idea. For 4., I recommand Piskounov's books